# Laravel Migration and seeding error

Tags: laravel

I am just starting to use the Laravel framework and its command prompt. I'm having trouble with the migration and seeding features, however.

I am developing on a WAMP server on a Windows 7 64-bit OS.

The database name is 'laravel', with the following two tables:

1. Migrations
2. users

The users table contains the following columns:

- id
- name
- email
- username
- password

I used the command line to generate a migration stored in `app\database\migrations\2014_06_24_221654_test.php`. I also created the migration and batch fields in the migration table.

I then want to seed an email to that table, so I used `DatabaseSeeder.php` in the database\seeds folder.

```
<?php class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder {

public function run()
{
    $this->call('UserTableSeeder');

    $this->command->info('User table seeded!');
}

}

class UserTableSeeder extends Seeder {

protected $fillable = array('email');

public function run()
{


    User::create(array('email' => 'jishadp369@gmail.com'));
}

}

?>
```

I then used the following command to seed the database

```
php artisan db:seed
```

However, I got the following exception:

```
 [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]

 SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field
 list' (SQL: insert into `users` (`email`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (ji
 shadp369@gmail.com, 2014-06-25 00:23:48, 2014-06-25 00:23:48))
```

How can I solve this? Do I need a model?

Comment: `$table->timestamps();` or `$table->nullableTimestamps();` in a table migration as described here: http://laravel.com/docs/schema#adding-columns

Comment: i dont get your answer

Comment: `Unknown column 'updated_at'` seems pretty clear to me. Laravel's Eloquent automatically manages the `created_at` and `updated_at` columns for you if you don't explicitly set `protected $timestamps = false;` on the model. It obviously takes them into account when seeding the database using the schema builder. While reading the schema builder documentation you undoubtedly had to see the `$table->timestamps()` method that automatically adds those two columns to the table.

Comment: What is the Feature REST in laravel

Comment: That is a new question, so add it accordingly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thats because your User model use timestamps fields.

Check your User model file.

You could find something like this `$this->timestamps = true` in your constructor. Change it to `false` and try again. If you don't find something like this, then add this attribute to the class:

```
public $timestamps = false;
```

I hope it works fine for you.

Comment: i have one more doubt ?

Comment: What is the Feature REST in laravel ?

Comment: You should probably take a look at this http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers